# In InfluxDB, can I get a list of hosts that have only certain measurements?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

We are using InfluxDB 0.10.1 for monitoring, and Grafana 2.6 for showing the results. In the Grafana Templating settings, I have a variable ($host) with this InfluxDB query:
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "host"

This gives me a list of all the hosts in the database. However, I was wondering, is there a way to add something to that query that will only choose the hosts that have a specific measurement showing up for them? For instance, we have WebSphere Liberty Profile only installed on a subset of the hosts in the database, and I would like only those hosts to show up in the dropdown for the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW TAG VALUES` does not accept a `WHERE` clause, so there's no way to further filter the query. See https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5245 for a closely related issue.

It can be done with a SELECT query, but you will have to be more specific as to how the WebSphere information is encoded. Are you saying that you use a different [measurement](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/concepts/glossary/#measurement) name for each type of host? Or is there an additional [tag](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/concepts/glossary/#tag) or [field](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/concepts/glossary/#field) on the WebSphere hosts?

Comment: With InfluxDB / Telegraf 0.10, there is now only one measurement in the database for each plugin type, for instance, WebSphere Liberty Profile:  
  
httpjson_liberty_stats  
 
  
And this measurement has multiple fields:  
jvm_cpu  
response_time  
  
It also has tags, such as 'host'.  
  
So what I want to do is only show a host if it has a specific measurement (in this case, 'httpjson_liberty_stats').    
    
[Sorry, I have edited this comment multiple times to try to fix the formatting, according to the mini-Markdown hints, but I can't get it to change.]

Comment: If `httpjson_liberty_stats` is the measurement name, and you only want to know the values of the tag `host` that exist in that measurement, then it should just be `SHOW TAG VALUES FROM httpjson_liberty_stats WITH KEY = host`. See https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/query_language/schema_exploration/#explore-tag-values-with-show-tag-values

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

Should be something like:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES ON "database" FROM "measurement" WITH KEY =~ /host/ WHERE product =~ /tag/
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use flux query for seeing list of all hosts

```
from(bucket: "test-bucket")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "cpu")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "usage_system")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["cpu"] == "cpu-total")
|> keep(columns: ["host"])
|> group()
|> unique(column: "host")
```